# TypeScript: Is it possible convert a constructor reference to its static reference on create a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For example

```js
class C1 {

    p1 = 1;

    static sp1 = 1;

}

type StaticReference<T> = typeof T; // T is a type, not a value, so doesn't work like that

let c1: StaticReference<C1>; //=> typeof C1 (on mouse over c1)

let c2: StaticReference<typeof C1>; //=> typeof C1
```

Comment: `typeof C1` is the static side of the class.. that is what you need to use.

Comment: But it's possible to convert `typeof C1` in `C1` with `InstanceType`, for example, but not the inverse.

Comment: The answer to this is unfortunately *no*.  There is no strongly typed `constructor` property, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841, so the type `C1` does not "point to" `typeof C1`.  Structurally speaking, an instance of `C1` does not differ from some random object of type `{p1: number}` and so there is no way to divine `typeof C1` from that.

Comment: Got it. Thank so much, jcalz.